# Cannot parse XML using Jackson, model never gets populated

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am trying to parse bellow xml using Jackson library but with no luck. I tried few things with my model, and I don't see the problem...

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<litre version="1.1" creator="Dummy Creator"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dummy.com/xmlschemas/DummyExtension.xsd>
    <metadata>
        <link href="dummy.com">
            <text>Dummy</text>
        </link>
        <time>2012-10-24T23:22:51.000Z</time>
    </metadata>
    <krt>
        <name>Untitled</name>
        <geskrt>
            <pkrt data1="123" data2="321">
                <ints>100</ints>
                <time>2012-10-24T22:21:15.000Z</time>
                <extensions>
                    <axtpx:DummyExtension>
                        <xtpx:hor>40000</xtpx:hor>
                    </axtpx:DummyExtension>
                </extensions>
            </pkrt>
            <pkrt data1="543" data2="345">
                <ints>100</ints>
                <time>2012-10-24T23:29:40.000Z</time>
                <extensions>
                    <axtpx:DummyExtension>
                        <xtpx:hor>50000</xtpx:hor>
                    </axtpx:DummyExtension>
                </extensions>
            </pkrt>
        </geskrt>
    </krt>
</litre>
```

POJO:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "litre")
public @Data class Model {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "pkrt")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Data> entries;

    public static @Data class Data {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "data1")
        private double dataOne;
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "data2")
        private double dataTwo;
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ints")
        private double inters;
        private String time;
        @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "xtpx:hor")
        private long hours;
    }
}
```

While trying to deserialize with:

```
Model model = mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                    .readValue(filePath.toFile(), Model.class);
```

parsing always passes with no exception, but entries list is always empty...

I would appreciate any help, thanx!

Comment: Your root object is element `litre` and not `geskrt` - are you aware of this?

Comment: Yeah, sort of a typo... I will edit question, thank you.

Comment: How should this work? You skip the elements `krt` and `geskrt` and assume that Jackson deserializes the inner part? When you want to use Jackson like this you have to model the complete XML structure as Java model and not only the part you deem useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most certainly have to do something like this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "litre")
public @Data class Litre {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "krt")
    private Krt krt;

    public static @Data class Krt {

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "geskrt")
        private Geskrt geskrt;
    }

    public static @Data class Geskrt {

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "pkrt")
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        private List<Pkrt> pkrt;
    }

    public static @Data class Pkrt {

        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "data1")
        private double dataOne;

        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "data2")
        private double dataTwo;

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ints")
        private double inters;

        private String time;

        @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "xtpx:hor")
        private long hours;
    }
}
```